# Trying to display an icon directly next to the report name

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to get the following icon from font-awesome to appear directly next to the report name.
This is how it currently looks:
[image]

I used a span tag thinking I would achieve this, but it is not working.  Does anyone have any recommendations as to what I should try next?

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span>
    <i class="fa m-r-15 text-left" style="font-weight: bold">
       <a style="color:orangered">Discounts</a>
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good to me here: https://jsfiddle.net/dzxv9Lco/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<span><i class="fa m-r-15 text-left" style="font-weight: bold"> <!-- Can you explain this line please? -->
     <a style="color:orangered">Discounts</a>
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
</span>
```

I think using span won't inline what's inside of it. You can use flexbox for that.
If you are using bootstrap or something like that you can try this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 d-flex">
   <a style="color:orangered">Discounts</a>
   <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
 </div>
```

In bootstrap "d-flex" says to that div "display: flex". You can learn more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).